# Entire functions such that $\limsup_{z \rightarrow \infty}\frac{|\log |f(z)||}{|z|} < \infty$

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

The problem I am working on is to find all entire functions satisfying $|f(z)| > 0$ for $|z|$ large and $$\limsup_{z \rightarrow \infty}\frac{|\log |f(z)||}{|z|} < \infty.$$

My guess is that these functions are the entire functions of order 1? Outside a sufficiently large ball centered at 0, $\log f$ is holomorphic and hence the numerator is really just $|\textrm{Re} \log f|$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Outside a sufficiently large ball centered at $0$, $\log f$ is holomorphic

Not really, unless your definition of "holomorphic" allows multi-valued functions, which would be unusual. For example $\log z$  does not have a holomorphic branch in $|z|>1$.

I think what you should do is:

1. Observe that $f$ has finitely many zeros.
2. Divide $f$ by a polynomial $p$ to get rid of zeros.
3. Take logarithm (*now* we know it's holomorphic, because the domain is simply connected, so the Monodromy theorem applies).
4. Argue that $\log (f/p)$ is a polynomial of pretty small degree.

Tangential remarks are below the cut.

---

Such functions have order $1$ **or less**. Also, not every function of order $1$ qualifies; it must have finite *type*. The standard way to describe such functions is to say thet are of [exponential type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_type).

Many (but not all)   functions of exponential type arise as Fourier transforms (the Paley-Wiener theorem). A complete characterization is provided by the Hadamard factorization theorem, which for such functions takes the simple form
$$
f(z) = Ce^{bz} z^k \prod_{n} \left( 1 - \frac z{z_n} \right) \exp\left( \frac z{z_n} \right)
$$
where $z_n$ are the nonzero zeros of $f$ ordered by magnitude and $k$ is the multiplicity of zero at zero. :)

When you have only finitely many zeros,   the above formula   simplifies.

Comment: How would one argue that $\log(f/p)$ is a polynomial of small degree?

Comment: @JKL629 It's bounded by a constant multiple of $\vert z \vert$. Cauchy estimate for derivatives. If you search the site for "entire function is a polynomial", you'll likely find a dozen copies of this argument.